# Hard cantiliver beam question (got I = 3.622x10^-6 and maximum load 23.9 KN) is this right I cant find the answere anywhere? Do you agree with me?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A horizontal cantilever with an inverted T cross-section is used as a hoist. The figure below shows
an overview of the beam loading conditions (left) and the beam cross-section (right). One end of the
beam is built in, and the vertical load is applied 1.0 m along the cantilever. If the maximum allowable
stress in the material is 330 MN/m2
, determine the maximum load that can be lifted. Neglect the
weight of the cantilever itself.[image]

Comment: What have you tried? We don't know what problem you are having with solving the question. This site is not set up to solve homework problems for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's calculate the section properties:

[image]

Note: $d_c$ is the offset distance of the center of the segment/block in consideration with respect to the centroid of the cross-section.

From the equation $\sigma = My/I$, we know the larger of $y_t$ and $y_b$ will yield the controlling (maximum) stress. **For this case, the topmost face controls,**

$M = \sigma_aI/y_t = 330*10^6*1.8*10^{-6}/0.0713 = 8330 N-m$

$Load = M/L = 8330/1 = 8330 N-m = 8.33 kN-m$

**Please check my calculation and verify the results.**

Comment: It is very important to know the methods to locate the centroid of a cross-section with irregular shapes. The first step is always to cut the shape into regular sections, then multiple the area of the sections with the distance (arm) between their geometric center and the (a wisely chosen) "Reference Datum/Line", from which location of the centroid is measured from. You can use the method of "subtraction" or "addition" of the sections to perform the calculation, and you can always verify the accuracy of your calculation using the other method, the results should be identical. Hope this helps.